# Cloud scheduler attempt finishes with status UNAVAILABLE everyday after triggering cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

My cloud scheduler triggers a cloud function everyday at 5PM but it started to fail after executing half of the process with the following log:
@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished","status":"UNAVAILABLE", "targetType":"HTTP"

After that it retries and the cloud function runs ok to the end

Can you please help me?

Comment: look at the Function logs. Check if the startup time for your function on the first invocation is too long. The first one fails, but the function still starts up but not fast enough.  That might explain why the second attempt succeeds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please indicate where I can check that?

Comment: On the page for your function is a tab named "LOGS".

Comment: is there a way to control or change the startup time so that the first invocation is not so long?

Comment: The primary factor for startup time is controlled by how you designed your application.